# How to get data to excel based on selected value?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I currently have this code and now I would need some help in making it to work based on what the user have selected.

```
public function downloadResponse(Request $request)
{

    $inputs = $request->input();
    $eType = $inputs['chapter_category'];

    Excel::create('Export data', function($excel,$eType)
    {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet)
        {
            $products = Dialog::where('eType', 'claim_type')->get();;
            foreach($products as $product)
            {
                $data[] = array(
                    $product->eType,
                    $product->eVal,
                    $product->intent,
                    $product->reply,
                );
            }
            $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
            $headings = array('Entity Type', 'Entity Value', 'Intent', 'Reply');
            $sheet->prependRow(1, $headings);
        });
    })->export('csv');

}
```

This line I have hard corded it:

```
$products = Dialog::where('eType', 'claim_type')->get();
```

So how do I get the `$eType` and replace it with '`claim_type`'?  If I straight put there will be error like below:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function 
>   App\Http\Controllers\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx::App\Http\Controllers\xxx\xxxx{closure}(),
>   1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what field names you have in your Dialog table, but...

$products = Dialog::where('eType', $eType)->get();

or

$products = Dialog::where('claim_type', $eType)->get();